# Torus opengl does not converge

Tags: python, opengl, graphics

I have a problem with my Torus in Opengl.

Here is my code on Python:

```
global numc, numt, r

twopi = 2 * math.pi

for i in range(0, numc):
    for j in range(0, numt):
        k = 1
        while k >= 0:
            s = (i + k) % numc + 0.5
            t = j % numt

            x = (1 + r * math.cos(s * twopi / numc)) * math.cos(t * twopi / numt)
            y = (1 + r * math.cos(s * twopi / numc)) * math.sin(t * twopi / numt)
            z = r * math.sin(s * twopi / numc)
            Colors_torus.extend([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
            Torus.extend([x, y, z])
            k -= 1
```

[On the screen below on the right side you may observe that the circles do not converge.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Cjh.png)

Comment: What I see is a problem with triangles connections, not with vertices generation.

Comment: @Ripi2

I use GL_QUADS_STRIP